SharePoint SPFx webpart hosted workbench very slow, displays lots of errors in console and has inconsistent behaviour
I am creating a SharePoint SPFx webpart.
Setup was as follows:
yo @microsoft/sharepoint   

And then I answered the prompts like this:
Solution Name: MyWebpartName 
Client-side component: WebPart 
Web part name: MyWebpartName 
Framework: No framework 

After some development, my package.json file looks like this:
{
  "name": "custom-home-page",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.17.1 <19.0.0"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-component-base": "1.19.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.19.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.19.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.19.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.19.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.19.0",
    "@pnp/sp": "^4.4.0",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "uikit": "^3.21.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.106.4",
    "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.20.1",
    "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.20.1",
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.7": "0.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.20.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.20.1",
    "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.30",
    "@types/webpack-env": "~1.15.2",
    "ajv": "^6.12.5",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}

The default contents of /config/serve.json are as follows (and I haven't changed it):
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/spfx-serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true,
  "initialPage": "https://{tenantDomain}/_layouts/workbench.aspx"
}

I have been taking the following steps to test the webpart locally:
gulp clean
gulp bundle
gulp package-solution
gulp serve --nobrowser

I then open this URL in the browser where I am signed in as a SharePoint Administrator:
https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx

I observe the following behaviour:

Before I have added the webpart, loading the workbench interface is extremely slow (30 seconds at least)

There are regularly lots of error messages in the dev tools console, such as:


ApiError
    at t.r (spserviceworker.js:7:533)
    at new t (spserviceworker.js:7:825)
    at spserviceworker.js:166:11414


It seems odd that the session id is being logged to the console

Sometimes my web part will be available for selection, sometimes it won't


Each code change is therefore taking me atleast 10 minutes to test.
To get the webpart into the live environment, I run these commands:
gulp clean
gulp bundle --ship 
gulp package-solution --ship 

and upload /sharepoint/solution/custom-home-page.sppkg to SharePoint, enable and add the app to a site, and add the webpart to a page, and it all works fine.
So it seems there is nothing wrong with the webpart, but rather the hosted workbench service itself.
This behaviour occurs in both Chrome and Edge.
My questions are:

Is this normal behaviour for the hosted workbench?

If so, is there an alternative?

If not, what can I do to improve the behaviour?



Update:
FYI
The smoothest/most performant experience I could get during local development was by following these steps:
gulp clean 
gulp build --verbose 
gulp bundle  
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 && gulp serve --nobrowser 

This last command will allocate more memory to the Node process.
This is required to avoid crashing when testing.
You will likely have to cancel and restart gulp serve if there are any issues.
Open the SharePoint Page where you want to add and test the web part.
Append this suffix to the end of the URL (this suffix will be displayed when running gulp serve as above):
?debug=true&noredir=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
You will see a prompt like this - select ‘Load debug scripts’.

You will then be able to add your local webparts to the SharePoint Page.
When you make changes locally, it will rebuild the webparts automatically.
Reload the page to see the changes.
After all this, you can follow your usual production build process, eg:
gulp clean
gulp build --ship 
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship 

This will output a package file at a location like this:
Your-SPFx-Solution-Name > sharepoint > src > your-spfx-solution-name.sppkg

any news about this? I've got the same issue. My workbench freezes when I try to add the webpart...

@AJRames - I have added an update to my question which describes the steps I took to get the smoothest/most performance development experience.  That's all I've got.
